# Python Selenium Click on a title

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click, title

I'm a newbie with Python and I'm trying to automate the booking.

For example, I would like to book today for the next week.

This is the code on the website:

```
<a href="#" class="dp-item" data-moment="October 29 2020" title="Thursday, 29 October 2020" style="width: 113px;">
    <div class="day row no-margin">
        <div class="day-number col-xs-12">29</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day-week">Thursday</div>
    <div class="month">October</div>
</a>
```

and below my code:

- I tried specifying a date, to check if it works but no luck:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Thursday, 29 October 2020']").click()
  ```
- At the end what I want to achieve is to use a variable like this:

  ```
  today = datetime.datetime.now() 
  nextweek = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='nextweek.strftime(%A %d %B %Y']").click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to do this is

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('nextweek.strftime(%A %d %B %Y').click()
```

**The code will look like**

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()  nextweek = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('nextweek.strftime(%A %d %B %Y').click()
```

It will find the class 'dp-item' and i think its better in this case
(I didn't test this code. If you get any error, please let me know)

Comment: thank you! I tested also that code in during my several tests but I got this: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: nextweek.strftime(%A %d %B %Y)

Comment: if there is no other tags with same class name you can use ```driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.dp-item')``` or ```driver.find_element_by_class_name('db-item')```, If the class if repeated two or ,more times you could use same code as to written with a f- string method ```driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[@title='{day}, {date} {month} {year} ']")```

Answer (score 0):

Try f-string in Python 3.8 and above, it's god send. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```py
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# assuming you have `driver` here
# driver = ...

today = datetime.datetime.now()
nextweek = datetime.timedelta(weeks=1) + today
nextweek_formatted = nextweek.strftime("%B %d %Y")
xpath = f'//a[@data-moment="{nextweek_formatted}"]'

# now getting <a> tag
link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, xpath))
link.click()
```

Good practice is to use `WebDriverWait` to find elements.

- If you find it normally, the page might not have enough time to load the element into DOM, might cause you false problem (`NoSuchElement` exception, even though it just needs 1-2 secs more to load the element).
- Use `EC.element_to_be_clickable` to truly wait for the element to be clickable, since you need to click it later.

Also, please implement `try` `except`, if `driver` cannot find element, it will raise `TimeoutException`. I don't implement it in the example code but you can try :).

Comment: Thank you. Exacty I got a TimeoutException. 
But I'm not sure if I understood. Why I should use try except, I mean if I cannot click on that element I cannot make a booking.

Comment: `TimeoutException` is for when you cannot find the element. In this case, you cannot find the button of "Oct 29 2020" for example. If you cannot find it, you should handle it. If your site only has a month available, and your next week is in Nov, you need to click on "Next month" element, then find the day.